# Map keycode to physical location

Tags: keyboard, gtk

Assuming the user has an "ISO Keyboard"[1] connected to a PC, is it possible to retrieve row and column from a keyboard scancode without asking the user to press all keys in sequence in order to create the map?

I want an image of the keyboard appearing on the screen, and the key the user as pressed should be highlighted. To be more specific, the solution should at least work under GTK+-3.0 on GNU/Linux.

- I tested the `hardware_keycode` in GTK (see `GdkEventKey`), which appear to be consistent across two machines. The documentation does not say from where it gets the raw code. Does it depend on the display server?
- If I do the same test in Windows 7 64 bit, using the `scancode` field from the `lParam` message parameter, the result appears to be consistent with the IBM XT keyboard. The same is true for Wine.

EDIT:

I do not care if the has the text 'Q' or 'A' printed on it. It is the position that is interesting.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#/media/File:ISO_keyboard_%28105%29_QWERTY_UK.svg

Comment: `GdkEventKey.hardware_keycode` will give you the scancode (though the numeric value has 8 added to it because X11 requires it), which [I've observed are usually the same across keyboard layouts](https://github.com/andlabs/libui/blob/ab97e26efcbe8f27559ab03329f57d5a19c56d0c/common/areaevents.c#L62-L73).

Comment: Have you gone anywhere with this since I posted that information?

Comment: Your info was exactly was I needed, though it requires me to have a lot of lookup tables. It would have been nice if there was some kind of system.

Comment: Yeah; unless someone else already made a table that you can use I wouldn't know; it's too late to change what was established in the early 1980s though ^^' Good luck!

Comment: @andlabs is that offset also true on other backends like Wayland and Windows?

Comment: It should be with Wayland (this is according to some of the core GTK+ devs as I pointed out in the comment in the code I linked earlier); not sure about Windows (check the GDK source?).